# Probability: the one true fish

Tags: math, machine-learning, probability, bayesian

I have exams in Machine Learning coming up and I need help answering this question.

> There are a million identical fish in a lake, one of which has
>   swallowed the One True Ring. You must get it back! After months of
>   effort, you catch another random fish and pass your metal detector
>   over it, and the detector beeps! It is the best metal detector money
>   can buy, and has a very low error rate: it fails to beep when near the
>   ring only one in a billion times, and it beeps incorrectly only one in
>   ten thousand times. What is the probability that, at long last, you’ve
>   found your precious ring?

This is my answer I worked out:

[image]

Is this the right way to work out this type of question and is that somewhat the correct answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math. Try posting to [math.se] instead.

Comment: @Juhana That's what I thought but when I was studying with people they have said to use the method above, Bayes Rule, and include the 1 million fish in the problem etc. My argument is that the question could have all this 'fluff' around it to trick people.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics (probability), not programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the probability of having the right fish given that the detector beeps, which is `P(A|B)`.

The `P(B|A) = 9999/10000` is the probability of the detector beeping given you have the right fish. However, we don't know if the fish you have is the right one. All you know is that the detector beeps, and you can't tell if it's a true positive with probability `P(B|A)` or a false positive with probability `P(B|not A)`.

Bayes' theorem lets you switch between `P(B|A)` and `P(A|B)`, so the other information isn't useless fluff. You do in need it all to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah yes that makes more sense. So do you think just by looking at it that `~0.09` is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, the `~0.09` is correct. Problems like this can be confusing to work through. I try to just remember that the things to the **left** of `|` are what I **don't** know, and the things to the **right** of `|` are what I **do** know.